# how to pass json array values ​to another page without navigation?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and my english is so-so and i couldn't find solution to my problem. My goal is to, once fetched a json array, to give the component the onPress navigator function so that, by clicking on the chosen item, it can send me back to a second page with the data of the array value.

```
export default class Brewery extends React.Component{


state ={
    breweries: []
}
async componentDidMount(){
    let url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) =>{ 
        console.log('JSON' , json)
        this.setState({breweries: json})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({breweries:[]})
    });
}
render(){
    return(
      
        <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
        data={this.state.breweries} 
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            
          
            <View style={styleSingleResult.box}>
              
              <Image   style={styleSingleResult.logo}
            source={{uri: item.thumbnailUrl}}  />
   
                <Text>{item.title}</Text> 
                </View>
                
               
             )}
             ListEmptyComponent={() =>
            <View>
                <Text>NSE Ciae DIOLADRO</Text>
            </View>}
    />
    )
}
```

}

I thought I would use

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NextPage', item)}>
```

and in the destination page the get:

```
<Text>{navigation.getParam('title')}</Text>
```

To recall the value of the item. Except that in the Brewery class I can't implement the "navigation" method .. How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

I read your requirement, So the solution is create a component name it for example:

```
<SecondScreen data={breweries} />
```

And when component mounted you can access data if exists or fetched well from server without any error.

I hope help you with my poor explaining